# Oauth Application github callback URL

Tags: github, oauth

I have used url using documentation : this is format

https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=&scope=user:email&state=

here is quick login page : http://www.bsdguru.in/accounts/login/ but its not working properly any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include the block of code you have used to attempt to integrate this for us to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: This is the URL :  https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=e9ee7e2567b0198dc085&scope=user:email&state=AOoYmbkX0MJq

Comment: Trying that login gives the following error in the URL.  `error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.`

It seems that the github integration isn't set up correctly.  Check that your Authorization callback URL is set up for your application.

Comment: osowskit above is current callback url can you tell me what i could change to make it work.

Comment: Based on your login flow, I'd expect the Authorization callback URL to be `http://www.bsdguru.in/accounts/github/login/` which would handle getting the token from GitHub.  Here is [GitHub documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-uri-mismatch) for this error